# Code not working while lopp with &&

Tags: java, while-loop

I don't understand why my code does not work see below I am supposed to transform this code

```
 public class Iteration { 
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         int x, y, z, sum, tal; 

         for(x=1;x<10;x++) 
             for(y=0;y<10;y++) 
                 for(z=0;z<10;z++){ 
                     tal=x*100+y*10+z; 
                     sum=(x*x*x)+(y*y*y)+(z*z*z); 
                     if(sum==tal) 
                         System.out.print(tal+" "); 
                 } 
     } 
}
```

into a code with a while loop, but it does not work the same! I dont understand why......

```
public class testasaker { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int sum, tal, x = 1, y = 0, z = 0; 

        while (x<10 && y<10 && z<10)  { 
            tal = x * 100 + y * 10 + z; 
            sum=(x*x*x)+(y*y*y)+(z*z*z); 
            if(sum==tal) 
                System.out.print(tal+" "); 
            z++; 
            y++;
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when `x` is 10?

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider formatting your code better.

Comment: I suggest you step through this with a debugger - or even try to work through it on paper. It's not clear *why* you expect it to work the same way, but I suspect you'll see why it doesn't as soon as you take it apart step by step.

Answer (score 3):

Your first code uses three nested loops and generates triples like

```
(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,2),...,(1,0,9),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),...(9,9,9)
```

While in your second code you only use one loop that increments each part of the triple simultaniously:

```
(1,0,0),(2,1,1),(3,2,2),....,(9,8,8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not replicate 3 loops with just one. You should make 3 nested loops

```
while (x<10 )  { 
    while (y<10){
        while (z<10)
     ..................
             z++;              
        }
        y++;
    } 
    x++;
}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact you can, but the counters incrementations would become tricky.

Comment: Of course you can! It just takes a bit more logic than incrementing all variables on every step

Comment: Zankister and Ordous are right. I just wanted to mean that this is the easiest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work the same way, because in the 1st you use nested loops, and in the 2nd you just use one loop with three variables incremented at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in for loop run from 1 to 10. when x is 1 and y is 1, z runs from 1 to 10. when z becomes 10, y becomes 2 and z starts from 1.

```
       while (x<10 && y<10 && z<10)  { 
            tal = x * 100 + y * 10 + z; 
            sum=(x*x*x)+(y*y*y)+(z*z*z); 
            if(sum==tal) 
                System.out.print(tal+" "); 
            z++; 
            if(z%10==0){
               y++;
               z=0;
            }
            if(y%10==0){
               x++;
               y=0;
               z=0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class testasaker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum, tal, x = 1, y = 0, z = 0;

        while (x < 10) {
            while (y < 10) {
                while (z < 10) {
                    tal = x * 100 + y * 10 + z;
                    sum = (x * x * x) + (y * y * y) + (z * z * z);
                    if (sum == tal)
                        System.out.print(tal + " ");

                    z++;
                }
                z=0;
                y++;
            }
            z=0;y=0;
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

The while loop should be separated and the variables `x, y, z` should be re-initialized.